# Socket.io connection over lan

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, lan

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and following Daniel Shiffman's p5.js tutorial. I made a fun little pong game and wanted it to take it to the next level by making it multiplayer. I want to start with the basics and just follow Daniel's Socket tutorial. I can successfully access my site and see my canvas. However, I want to take it to the next level by making it available over the LAN. I am not sure how to do this, and I am having some trouble. Here is the client code I used:

```
var socket;

function setup() {
  socket = io.connect();
  createCanvas(200, 200);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 60, 60);
}
```

The server code is:

```
// Imports
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

// Create Local host
var app = express();
var server = app.listen('3000')
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Sockets
var io = socket(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

// New Connection
function newConnection(socket) {
  console.log("New Connection: " + socket.id);
}

console.log("Server running...");
```

if needed here is my index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Learning Sockets</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/libraries/addons/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/libraries/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/libraries/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <script src="/libraries/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Keep in mind that I am a beginner. I have tried looking at other posts, but the answers were too complicated, and in the end, I don't think that it solved my problem. Not sure if it matters but I do have node.js, express, and socket.io installed. I have tried connecting by using http://my-ip:3000. I can connect from my computer via localhost:3000 and my-IP:3000. But when I try to connect from another computer it doesn't work. And yes I am connected to the same network.

Daniel Shiffman's playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6b36TzJidYfIYwTFEq3K5qH

Comment: It's likely your firewall blocking connections. You should unblock port 3000 in your firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I looked at my IP address again, and I used the wrong one. Silly me. PROBLEM SOLVED :D